# cmake - error in compile regular expression

Tags: regex, cmake

I have a string: `1.0.2-1` and I need to get a substring: `1.0.2` Following regular expression works fine in c++:

```
std::regex myReg(".+?(?=-)");
```

When I try to use that regex in cmake:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH ".+?(?=-)" OUTPUT $VER)
```

I get errors:

```
[INFO] RegularExpression::compile(): Nested *?+.
[INFO] RegularExpression::compile(): Error in compile.
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: Can you just try `[^-]+`? Or `^[^-]+` (to only look from the beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CMake regex syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/string.html) does not support lazy quantifiers, hence the error message.

Since you need to get the first match with characters other than `-`, you can use

```
[^-]+
```

Or (to tell the engine to only look for a match from the beginning of the string):

```
^[^-]+
```