# cmake string REGEX REPLACE replaces only the first occurence

Tags: regex, string, cmake, replace

I try to replace all occurences in a code file header (Linux with CMake 3.16.3)

```
file(READ file.h FILE_CONTENT)
string(REGEX REPLACE "old_prefix(_.*_postfix)" "new_prefix\\1" FILE_CONTENT ${FILE_CONTENT})
file(WRITE file.h ${FILE_CONTENT})
```

but only the first occurrence is replaced. I expected all occurrences will be replaced like described in the CMake description. What do I wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-replace) says it replaces all matches. Can you show sample input and the expected result?

Comment: You probably need to use a non-greedy quantifier. Otherwise the regexp matches everything from the first `old_prefix` to the last `_postfix`.

Comment: It's simply a header protection like
```
#ifndef old_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
#define old_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
#endif // old_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
```
results in
```
#ifndef new_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
#define old_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
#endif // old_prefix_<file_name>_postfix
```
but all three occurrences should be replaced

Comment: if I do it line by line also other occurrences are replaced like
old_prefix_<file_name>_<something else>postfix<something else>

Comment: Please put it in the question so it can be formatted readably.

Comment: As I said, use a non-greedy quantifier. Change `.*` to `.*?`.

Comment: .*? Is not working
[build] RegularExpression::compile(): Nested *?+.
[build] RegularExpression::compile(): Error in compile.
[build] CMake Error at drp/CMakeLists.txt:276 (string):
[build]   string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE failed to compile regex
[build]   "prefix(_.*?_postfix)".

Comment: Sorry, apparently Cmake doesn't support lazy quantifiers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148043/cmake-error-in-compile-regular-expression

Comment: Is there a character that can't appear between `old_prefix_` and `_postfix`? Use `[^character]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Everything which is allowed for #ifndef/#define old_prefix_<file name>_postfix can happen

Comment: Then I think Cmake's regular expressions aren't powerful enough for this, you'll need to use something else, like `sed`.